# Loading data into a temp table?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005

I intend to load data from several temp tables (t_source) located in different databases 
and servers into one temp table (t_main) using C# code and SQL server. After that, I want 
to write data of t_main into a text file.

My question is that can this cause SQL server to run out of memory (because it will be storing the t_main) ? What is the maximum amount of data that I can store in a temp table of a Sql server 2005 or 2008 database ?

Comment: How big is your disk drive where tempdb is located?

Comment: @AaronBertrand - I am not sure. But typically, the free space is 10-20GB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Table size (static or temporary) is only limited by available storage space.  They are not stored in memory.

Comment: So, to avoid the disk out of memory error also, populate temp table with a small part of the data set at a time ?

Comment: "disk out of memory" is confusing - are you talking about running out of _disk space_ or _memory_?

Comment: yes, that is what i meant since sql server would be paging out rows to hard disk when it needs more memory, right ?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question - your storage is limited by disk space, not physical (or virtual) memory - the system will swap out to disk when necessary but that doesn't _limit_ how much you can store.

Comment: How does that not limit how much can be stored ? Any other factors to determine that limit ?

Comment: @Trojan.ZBOT so if your system only has 4 GB of RAM, do you expect you could only ever store 4 GB of data in tempdb? Memory <> storage.

Comment: Physical storage is the only limit.  Additional memory only improves _performance_

Answer (score 0):

In SQL Server, a temp table has the same storage limits as an ordinary table.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190768.aspx